# I keep Getting KeyError: 'tried' Whenever I Tried to Run Django Dev Server from Remote Machine

Tags: python, django

I am running django 1.1.1 on python2.6.1, and did start the  django web server like this

> `manage.py runserver 192.0.0.1:8000`

then tried to connect to the django dev web server on http://192.0.0.1:8000/

keep getting this message on the remote computer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 279, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 651, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    return debug.technical_404_response(request, e)

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 247, in technical_404_response
    tried = exception.args[0]['tried']

KeyError: 'tried'
```

what i am doing wrong ?

it seen to work ok if i run http://192.0.0.1:8000/ on the computer that runs the Django web server and have that ip 192.0.0.1:8000

Comment: What release of Django?  There are many out there these days (pre-1, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ...) and they may behave differently in respects such as these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the revision logs of that file you'll see that django has recently started catching the KeyError that is raised in that try block.

The log message reads "Ensured generating debug 404 page won't raise a key error. Thanks pigletto."

See the ticket http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12083 and the changeset http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/12679

So, I would check if you're raising a debug 404 page, or if any of the other comments in the ticket jump out of you.

Hope that helps!

**Update**: After looking at the code a little bit closer, I'd take a good look at your urls.py file for any mistakes in the url resolving regex.  Are you doing url('') instead of ('^$') for the root/homepage?

Comment: This doesn't exactly explain why you're getting errors on the remote machine, and not the local machine.  Be sure to double check that you're using the same version of Django on your dev server and remote server.

Go into the python and:
    import django
    django.VERSION